# The operating system is not supported

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to install Ansys in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. After writing ./install in the terminal(terminal is opened at the location where the install file is present). I am getting the error.

*** Error:   This operating system is not supported.

```
         Currently-supported Linux versions include:
         - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 64-bit: Versions 7
         - SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 64-bit: Versions 12 & 15
```

As I am new to Ubuntu. I could not figure out the error. Previously, I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0. I got the same problems there. Please help me to fix the issue

Regards

Sandeep

Comment: The error seem like it's in plain language: Ubuntu is not supported by that software. There is nothing to "fix". You chose the wrong combination of OS and Software.

Comment: It seems to be a closed source proprietary software. You can ask the support channel of the software to support Ubuntu. We cannot do anything about it.